# what's wrong with my firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

I am using IE 8 & Mozilla Firefox 3.6.

In Firefox on some of the sites like `stackoverflow.com` - the web pages is not loading correctly. I found that the link http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e47b7cdedc4a results in `server not found` error and because of this I am not able load site properly on Mozilla Firefox.

But they are loading properly in IE.
Did I disable something ?

Comment: Not really a programming question, try http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/

Answer (score 2):

Disable any addons you have downloaded and try again, if it works start adding your addons back one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Clear your browser cache. I faced the same problem, [as I had discussed in chat.meta.so](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/111450)

[image]

> Failed to load resource for sstatic.net/superuser/all.css?v=066afceba0b5
>
> not an extensions problem
>
> I use 4 - Adbock, IETab, Autopager & hide the anniversary bar userscript, disabled and still the same
>
> cache problem, it was
>
> cleared cache for the past hour and now we're back on

Comment: ya clearing cache i already did but it didn't solve my problem but when u said this i tried it once again ..i found firefox safemode icon. started firefox in safemode & i checked all option(disabled) now everything was fine...
thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurs because css files for this website is not correctly loaded. All static(js, css etc.) files of [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/) sites (like [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [superuser](https://superuser.com/), [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/) etc.) are located at http://sstatic.net/ . This problem may occurs for the reasons below:

1. Your firewall / antivirus program blocked the [http://sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net/) website.
2. You have very slow internet connection. For that all the component of the page is not loaded correctly.
3. Your service provider blocked [http://sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net/) website. In that case contact your service provider for details.
4. One of the plugin / extension / your browser blocks or replaces the original css script.

You can try to open this website using a proxy site(like http://www.kproxy.com/) to make sure that website is working correctly or not.